# log4j Error in building Corda sample project

Tags: corda

When I build the sample corda project with gradle on windows (gradlew.bat deployNodes)
I see the error about DELETE command in log4j:

2019-10-28 16:30:47,207 main ERROR Delete contains invalid attributes "IfFileName", "IfLastModified"
2019-10-28 16:30:47,213 main ERROR Missing Delete conditions: unconditional Delete not supported
2019-10-28 16:30:47,217 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction for element Delete: java.lang.IllegalArgume
ntException: Unconditional Delete not supported java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:964)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:904)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:548)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:637)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext.start(AsyncLoggerContext.java:76)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at net.corda.core.utilities.KotlinUtilsKt.contextLogger(KotlinUtils.kt:42)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion$logger$2.invoke(CordaCliWrapper.kt:108)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion$logger$2.invoke(CordaCliWrapper.kt:107)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion.getLogger(CordaCliWrapper.kt:65535)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion.access$getLogger$p(CordaCliWrapper.kt:107)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:142)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:106)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1173)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$800(CommandLine.java:141)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1367)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1335)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:1243)
        at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1526)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:73)
        at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unconditional Delete not supported
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.(DeleteAction.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.createDeleteAction(DeleteAction.java:212)
        ... 43 more

2019-10-28 16:30:47,606 main ERROR Null object returned for Delete in DefaultRolloverStrategy.
2019-10-28 16:30:47,736 main ERROR Delete contains invalid attributes "IfFileName", "IfLastModified"
2019-10-28 16:30:47,737 main ERROR Missing Delete conditions: unconditional Delete not supported
2019-10-28 16:30:47,739 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction for element Delete: java.lang.IllegalArgume
ntException: Unconditional Delete not supported java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:964)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:904)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:548)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:637)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext.start(AsyncLoggerContext.java:76)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at net.corda.core.utilities.KotlinUtilsKt.contextLogger(KotlinUtils.kt:42)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion$logger$2.invoke(CordaCliWrapper.kt:108)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion$logger$2.invoke(CordaCliWrapper.kt:107)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion.getLogger(CordaCliWrapper.kt:65535)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase$Companion.access$getLogger$p(CordaCliWrapper.kt:107)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:142)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:106)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1173)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$800(CommandLine.java:141)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1367)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1335)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:1243)
        at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1526)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:73)
        at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unconditional Delete not supported
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.(DeleteAction.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.createDeleteAction(DeleteAction.java:212)
        ... 43 more

I got latest verison of corda samples. (from master branch). I encounter the same problem with other branches.
My jdk version is 1.8.0_212.
I used cordapp-examples project

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about the regional settings of my computer.

By defining an Environment variable

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US  -Duser.region=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.variant=US
```

I solved the problem.

Thanks all for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are pulling in JAR files from somewhere other than those specified by the Corda build.

The default branch for the samples is `release-V4` and that is the one I'm using. I run the following and it works fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/corda/samples
cd cordapp-example
gradlew deployNodes
```

I'd check that your classpath variable isn't set (as this will cause additional JAR files in those directories to be included when running Corda) by running :

```
echo %CLASSPATH%
```

Additionally, from the command-line I'd run:

```
java -version
where java
```

To make sure the version of java you *think* you're picking up *is* the one you are picking up.

Comment: I did the same things. But I received the same error.
git clone https://github.com/corda/samples
cd cordapp-example
gradlew deployNodes

I echoed CLASSPATH variable in gradlew.bat
CLASSPATH: D:\CORDA\sample\cordapp-example\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar

java -version
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)

where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe

When I change the branch to release-V3 it works.But for release-V4 it gives these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue related to log4j:

> the log4j2 error unable to invoke factory method in class class RollingFileApender
>
> Error while generating node info file

To fix this (on windows), I took the following steps:

1. Right click on MyPC
2. Click advanced system settings
3. Click environment variables
4. Change JAVA_HOME to point to same jdk directory being used in IntelliJ for corDapp. (I changed mine from OpenJDK\jdk-13.0.1 to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231)
5. Restart IntelliJ and rerun `./gradlew deployNodes`